# Add JavaScript animation on Joomla website

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

sorry for my bad english.

I'm trying to add an animated doughnout chart on the home page.

But I can't use JavaScript, what extension should I use (I've tried some without success) ?

How can I activate Jquery for the entire website ?

Can I add HTML tags in a module and then use them with JavaScript ?

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery is javascript. How to include javascript in joomla is very well documented. Read the manual

Comment: Thanks for that great information.
Jquery is JavaScript, really ? I can't believe it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to add an animated doughnout chart on the home page.
>
> But I can't use JavaScript, what extension should I use (I've tried
>   some without success) ?

The best alternative to a JavaScript chart would be an [HTML5 chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/). However, you would still need some JavaScript to help it.

A [Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer.html) (or [Silverlight](https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/)) chart could be used without JavaScript. However, you will loose device support as the browser needs a special plugin to run those.

[Artio](https://www.artio.net/) created a [Flash Charts](http://joomla25.demo.artio.cz/en/flash-charts-demo-instructions) component that would create such charts. However, it has since been replaced by [Animated JavaScript Charts](http://www.artio.net/joomla-extensions/fusioncharts-for-joomla). You may be able to obtain the older version, still. But, in either case, the component itself still required JavaScript to load the charts and simply used Flash for the animation.

On a side note, I'm pretty sure Joomla! (back-end) does not even work properly without JavaScript, so either you are mistaken and CAN use JavaScript, or you are not going to be able to accomplish this. If you only want to keep JavaScript from the front-end (and leave it in the back-end), you will likely need to build the charts offsite with all the data in Flash and then embed the Flash file directly.

> How can I activate Jquery for the entire website ?

Add the following line to the `<head>` section at the top of your template's `index.php` file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Can I add HTML tags in a module and then use them with JavaScript ?

Yes, you can reference any HTML tags from a module (or any component/plugin/etc. that adds content to the page) using [jQuery selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp).